# Call lambda with the cartesian product of values in multiple input vectors

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates

I have several vectors of either `int`s or `double`s:

```
std::vector<int>    iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<double> jv = { .5, 1., 1.5, 2. };
std::vector<int>    kv = { 5, 4, 3, 2 };
```

I need to process the cartesian product of each vector:

```
for (int i : iv)
{
    for (double j : jv)
    {
        for (int k : kv)
        {
            process(i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to flatten this into a single call

```
product(iv, jv, kv, [=](int i, double j, int k)
    {
        process(i, j, k);
    });
```

- The number of input vectors is variable
- The types stored in the input vectors are variable

Is this possible? (I'm using C++14)

Comment: have you seen that, does it help anyhow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206965/cartesian-product-using-iterators-and-variadic-templates ?

Comment: `product(std::tuple<...>, functor );` should be possible

Comment: How about https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1view_1_1cartesian__product__fn.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a short recursive version that just works with any iterables. It takes everything by `const&` for simplicity:

```
template <typename F>
void product(F f) {
    f();
}

template <typename F, typename C1, typename... Cs> 
void product(F f, C1 const& c1, Cs const&... cs) {
    for (auto const& e1 : c1) {
        product([&](auto const&... es){
            f(e1, es...);
        }, cs...);
    }   
}
```

Which would be:

```
product(process, iv, jv, kv);
```

Comment: perhaps you could explain the code for those of us stuck with C++11 ...

Comment: @Walter Which part do you need explanation for? If you try to verbally explain to somebody how to do cartesian product, this is probably the algorithm you'll end up with. You could do this in C++11 too, just need to write a type trait to go from container type to const reference.

Answer (score 3):

You use C++14 so you can use `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence_for`...

I propose to call `product()` passing first the function and next the vectors.

I mean

```
 product([=](int i, double j, int k) { process(i, j, k); }, iv, jv, kv);
```

This way you can use variadic templates for vectors.

I propose also the following helper functions

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename Tp>
void productH (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, Tp const & tp)
 { f(std::get<Is>(tp)...); }

template <typename F, typename Is, typename Tp, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
void productH (F f, Is const & is, Tp const & tp, T0 const & t0, Ts ... ts)
 { 
   for ( auto const & val : t0 )
      productH(f, is, std::tuple_cat(tp, std::tie(val)), ts...);
 }
```

so `product()` simply become

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void product (F f, Ts ... ts)
 { productH(f, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, std::make_tuple(), ts...); }
```

The idea is extract and accumulate in a `std::tuple` the values. Given the final `std::tuple`, call the function extracting the values from the `std::tuple` using `std::get` and the indexes generated with `std::index_sequence_for`.

Observe that there is no need that vector are `std::vector`s; the can be `std::queue`, `std::array`, etc.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename Tp>
void productH (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &, Tp const & tp)
 { f(std::get<Is>(tp)...); }

template <typename F, typename Is, typename Tp, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
void productH (F f, Is const & is, Tp const & tp, T0 const & t0, Ts ... ts)
 { 
   for ( auto const & val : t0 )
      productH(f, is, std::tuple_cat(tp, std::tie(val)), ts...);
 }

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void product (F f, Ts ... ts)
 { productH(f, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, std::make_tuple(), ts...); }

void process (int i1, double d1, int i2)
 { std::cout << '[' << i1 << ',' << d1 << ',' << i2 << ']' << std::endl; }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int>       iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   std::array<double, 4u> jv = { { .5, 1., 1.5, 2. } };
   std::deque<int>        kv = { 5, 4, 3, 2 };

   product([=](int i, double j, int k) { process(i, j, k); }, iv, jv, kv);
 }
```

Unfortunately you can't use C++17 where you can avoid the `std::index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence_for`/`std::get()` part and use `std::apply()` as follows

```
template <typename F, typename Tp>
void productH (F f, Tp const & tp)
 { std::apply(f, tp); }

template <typename F, typename Tp, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
void productH (F f, Tp const & tp, T0 const & t0, Ts ... ts)
 { 
   for ( auto const & val : t0 )
      productH(f, std::tuple_cat(tp, std::tie(val)), ts...);
 }

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void product (F f, Ts ... ts)
 { productH(f, std::make_tuple(), ts...); }
```

Comment: Upvoted for using iterators (via ranged for) instead of indices as I did.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. It's probably not optimal, but it works.

One downside is that it works only with random-access containers.

I changed the call syntax from `product(a, b, c, lambda)` to `product(a, b, c)(lambda)` since this one is easier to implement.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename ...P, std::size_t ...I>
auto product_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, const P &...lists)
{
    return [&lists...](auto &&func)
    {
        std::size_t sizes[]{lists.size()...};
        std::size_t indices[sizeof...(P)]{};
        std::size_t i = 0;

        while (i != sizeof...(P))
        {
            func(lists[indices[I]]...);

            for (i = 0; i < sizeof...(P); i++)
            {
                indices[i]++;
                if (indices[i] == sizes[i])
                    indices[i] = 0;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}

template <typename ...P>
auto product(const P &...lists)
{
    return product_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(P)>{}, lists...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<float> b = {0.1, 0.2};
    std::vector<int> c = {10, 20};

    product(a, b, c)([](int x, float y, int z)
    {
        std::cout << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << '\n';
    });

    /* Output:
    1  0.1  10
    2  0.1  10
    3  0.1  10
    1  0.2  10
    2  0.2  10
    3  0.2  10
    1  0.1  20
    2  0.1  20
    3  0.1  20
    1  0.2  20
    2  0.2  20
    3  0.2  20
    */
}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ac865bf21ebbdd5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is by way of explaining Barry's code:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename F>
void product(F f) {
    f();
}

template <typename F, typename C1, typename... Cs> 
void product(F f, C1 const& c1, Cs const&... cs) {
       product([&] ( auto const&... es){ 
            f(c1,es...);
          },
       cs...);
}

void process(int i, double j, int k)
{
  std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   product(process, 1, 1.0, 2);
}
```

This is just a fancy way of calling `process.` The point is `f(c1,es...)` creates a curried function of `f` where the first parameter is locked in to `c1`. Thus when `cs` becomes empty, all the parameters are curried and `f()` lands up calling `process(1,1.0,2)` Notice that this currying is available only at compile time not  run time.